# Converting datetime into a general format in python script

Tags: python, datetime

is there a solution to convert an general format for a datetime in a python script without placing on every variable something like this:

```
variable.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

best regards

Comment: `str(variable)` should give what you want. But it will also have the timestamp. The format would look something like `2018-02-18 02:34:43.696444`.

Answer (score 0):

This is where you use a function, e.g.:

```
import datetime

f = lambda x: x.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

f(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Returns:

```
'18-02-2018'
```